# Cast IA5String to a String

Tags: java, string, casting

I wrote this code to get an Int and a String with the ASN.1 generated classes. It work fine with Integer but I don't understand how to cast the IA5String to a String.

```
ServerFirstResponse response1 = new ServerFirstResponse();
ASN1Integer serverNumber= response1.serverInt;
 int serverNumbervalue = (int)serverNumber.getValue();

IA5String serverString=response1.serverString;
String serverString = (String) serverString.getBytes();
```

this is the description of the ASN Sequence

```
ServerFirstResponse ::= SEQUENCE {                

   serverInt    INTEGER ,        

   serverString     IA5String  

 }
```

Comment: Does `serverString.toString()` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e10688/com/octetstring/vde/syntax/IA5String.html) do not list a `getBytes` method but a `getValue` method. Either way, you cannot cast a `byte[]` to a `String`.

You can either pass the `bytes` to the `String` constructor

`new String(serverString.getBytes())`

or

just use `toString` as `serverString.toString()`